# I can't make my program print newlines - Python

Tags: python, newline

The code is quite short so I put it here:

```
prog = []
# Reading the database from a file
try:
    with open('prog.txt') as f:
        progA = f.read().splitlines()
    for n in range(len(progA)/2):
        num = n*2
        prog.append([progA[num],progA[num+1]])
except:
    print "Something went wrong"
ch = 1
while True:
    nR = True
    print prog[ch-1][0]
    # Getting input
    while nR:
        inp = raw_input(">>> ")
        try:
            inp = int(inp)
            if str(inp) in prog[ch-1][1]:
                ch = inp
                nR = False
            else:
                print "You can't move to that channel"
        except:
            print "That isn't a number"
```

And the contents of the file (prog.txt):

```
DATABASE\nBrowse by entering the number you see after the link.\n> VERSION (3)
23
VERSION\nThis is the latest version.\n> Main menu (1)
1
```

The code works, but not as I wanted. It prints the newlines as it would be any other text, not with an actual new line.

Comment: `\n` in prog.txt is treated as normal character, thats why!

Answer (score 1):

If you want newline characters in your database file, use actual newline characters, created with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. If your file contains the character `\` followed by the character `n`, those characters will be interpreted literally. Either create a database file with actual newlines, or preprocess it to replace the literal `\n` with an actual newline, with `.replace('\\n', '\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` is not converted to a real newline when you read it from a file. Compare

```
>>> print "foo\nbar"
foo
bar
>>> print raw_input()
foo\nbar
foo\nbar
```

`\n` is something that is processed by Python when creating `str` objects from string literals.